# IE8 not showing input type text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm facing an issue that IE8 doesn't show borders for input div. The input is in the page, I can click in it and write in it but it isn't visible(see screenshots).

IE8 screenshot
[image: IE8]
Chrome screenshot.
[image: Chrome]

The second input is added dynamically via jQuery. How can I make the first input visible?

Code

```
<table id="footable">
<tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" class="fooClass"/></td><td><select class="course"><option value="-1" type=""></option></select></td></tr>
</table>
```

the `fooClass` doesn't have any style. I use it just as jQuery identifier.

I've already tried to add `border: 1px solid black;` to `style` attribute to the input but it didn't help...

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Comment: Post your CSS code, for #footable and .fooClass. There are any kind of code that can be reseting your borders?

Comment: try to give the fooClass an border

Comment: Use the f12 developer tools and inspect that input field. Check the CSS that is applied to it to see if there are any rules that remove the border

Comment: Tested your code and it work in IE. The input test showed.

Comment: A browser zoom level issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to define the outline? That maybe helps:

```
outline: 1px solid black;
```